# how to get the attribute value of 'width' property

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my progress bar http://jsfiddle.net/vjNpj/2247/ , I want the span (percentage value) can change together when the width of the div changed. like when the width is 50%, the span will display 50%..

what I can think of is attr(), but how to get its value?

I tried this but not working

```
var percent = $('#progressbar > div').attr('width');
alert(percent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vjNpj/2258/) that achieves what you are after

```
$progress_bar = $('#progressbar');
var progressbar_width = Math.floor(100 * ($progress_bar.find('div').width()) / $progress_bar.width())
$progress_bar.find('span').text(progressbar_width + '%')
```

You will have to call this code everytime you update the width of the progress bar.

Comment: TQ very very much.. what I need now is round off~ TQ!!

Comment: var progressbar_width = Math.floor(100 * ($progress_bar.find('div').width()) / $progress_bar.width()) + 1;

Comment: You can use `Math.ceil` in that case instead of `Math.floor` since that will round the float up rather than down.

Answer (score 3):

Lets understand this first

> The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter
>   returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former
>   returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .width()
>   method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a
>   mathematical calculation.

So you can do,

```
alert($('#progressbar > div').css("width"));  // 388
alert($('#progressbar > div').prop("width")); // 388px;
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JPRyX/1/)** for more understanding

Answer (score 0):

```
var percent = $('#progressbar > div').width();
```

or

```
var percent = $('#progressbar > div').css('width');


alert(percent);
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/vjNpj/2251/)**

Comment: got it, it's tht simple, but how to convert to percent? look like I gonna do some math..

Comment: first get your total div width 

now when you get width then calculate % with the total width and show as you want

Answer (score 0):

Hey `width` is an attribute just like `value` is an attribute, so you may only want to get width not **value** of width.And for that I recommend answer by amit aggarwal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some mathematical calculation for this work -

```
var percent = $('#progressbar div').width();
var Percent_Load = parseInt((percent * 100)/ $('#progressbar').width(), 10)
alert(Percent_Load);
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/vjNpj/2257/)